# How to make a form in React to submit more than once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a single page application made of 2 components. Also I have a navigation bar (a component as well) with a input text to preform searches. The navbar is something like that

```
const Navbar = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    dest: null
  });

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let query = e.target.query.value;
    e.target.query.value = '';
    setState({
        dest: '/search/' + query
    });
  };

  return (

    //some other markup
    <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <input
            type="text"
            name="query"
            placeholder=""
        />
    </form>
  );
}
```

also after the form there is a Redirect, so when you type something and hit enter, it redirects to the Search module to perform the search.

All works fine, but If I make a search, and then I click a search result, and then I click search again, the form does not submit, unless I change what I am searching for.

I suppose is because I need to reload the navbar component?

thanks

Comment: Well, the results won't change if you don't change what you're searching for, right? It's probably still submitting properly.

Comment: correct. but if I make a search, then I click a search result, and I get to another page, and from there I want to make the same search again, I can't do it.

Comment: It's not updating because you're not updating the state - hence why it only searches again after you change the input. My suggestion would be to clear the state after getting your search result so that when you make the same search again it recognises it as a state change.

Comment: I am doing a setState in the handleSubmit function, isn't that enough?

Comment: No, it's not enough. You set it... but then that's it. It needs to change to affect the rest of the process after that... since it never gets cleared out, it doesn't change. Since it doesn't change, it doesn't know to do the search again. So you need something in the process to clear it out.

Comment: ok I get in, in theory, but I'll need a more practical example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the lifecycle method componentDidUpdate() which is called anytime state is updated.

You could also attach an onChange event handler on your input form and search instantly, again with componentDidUpdate()

For example:

```
<input
        type="text"
        name="query"
        placeholder=""
        value={this.state.inputValue}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
    />

handleChange (e) {
  console.log('called handle change');
  this.setState({inputValue: e.target.value});
}
```

Comment: They are using functional components and hooks as opposed to the more traditional class components. So I don't think that `componentDidUpdate()` would work. But I could be wrong.